# user interface inside QSystemTrayIcon context menu

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

I'm creatig tray icon application and i want create advanced context menu, like on pictures below, but i only know, how to create simple menues with

```
QMenu* menu = new QMenu()
menu->addAction(QIcon(), "item", item1Click);
trayIcon->setContextMenu(menu);
```

How can i do this?
[image: first example]
[image: second example]

Comment: Your question is a bit vague but I suspect [`QWidgetAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidgetaction.html) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I meant that I know how to create a simple context menu. I described this in the question itself. But this will be the most common menu with items in the list, and I want to create an advanced menu, as in the pictures. Beautifully place buttons, draw tables, and more.

Comment: Right, and that's what `QWidgetAction` allows you to do by associating a `QWidget` with a `QAction` rather than being limited to text/icons etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, is supose, it's better to show you code:

main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtGui/QIcon>
#include <QtWidgets/QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenu>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidgetAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QSpinBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>

class SpinBoxAction : public QWidgetAction
{
public:
    SpinBoxAction (const QString& title) : QWidgetAction (NULL)
    {
        QWidget* Widget = new QWidget (NULL);
        QHBoxLayout* Layout = new QHBoxLayout();
        QLabel* Label = new QLabel (title);
        Layout->addWidget (Label);
        SpinBox = new QSpinBox(NULL);
        Layout->addWidget (SpinBox);
        Widget->setLayout (Layout);

        setDefaultWidget(Widget);
    }

    QSpinBox* spinBox()
    {
        return SpinBox;
    }

private:
    QSpinBox* SpinBox;
};

class Reciever : public QObject
{
private:
    QSystemTrayIcon* trayIcon;
public:
    Reciever()
    {

    }
    void setup(QSystemTrayIcon* trayIcon)
    {
        this->trayIcon = trayIcon;
    }

    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void action(int i)
    {
        trayIcon->showMessage("changed", "spin box value has been changed", QSystemTrayIcon::NoIcon, 1000);
    }

    void onActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
    {
        trayIcon->showMessage("activated", "tray icon has been activated", QSystemTrayIcon::NoIcon, 1000);
    }
};

#endif // MAIN_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <main.h>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtGui/QIcon>
#include <QtWidgets/QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenu>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidgetAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Reciever* reciever = new Reciever();

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSystemTrayIcon* trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon(":/images/abc.png"));
    if (!trayIcon->isSystemTrayAvailable()) exit(1);

    QMenu* menu = new QMenu();
    SpinBoxAction* spinBoxAction = new SpinBoxAction("Action Title");
    menu->addAction(spinBoxAction);

    QObject::connect(spinBoxAction->spinBox(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), reciever, SLOT(action(int)));

    trayIcon->setContextMenu(menu);
    trayIcon->setVisible(true);

    QObject::connect(trayIcon, &QSystemTrayIcon::activated, reciever, &Reciever::onActivated);
    reciever->setup(trayIcon);

    return app.exec();
}
```

And it leads to simple list menu with one empty element:

[image: result of this]

Comment: I've been trying to use a QWidgetAction with QSystemTrayIcon, but my custom widget shows up blank (like in your last screenshot). Any idea why that is? Adding the same QWidgetAction() in a normal context menu works perfectly. It's the system tray context menu that seems to cause the issue